# Bad Performance When Uploading Large Data With Libcurl

Tags: c, performance, http, curl, tcp

We have an application written in C, running on both Windows and Linux, which uses libcurl's easy interface to interact with an Apache server via an HTTP API over the internet. Normally, the API transactions are short, and bandwidth performance is inconsequential, but recently we have had to start working with a transaction which sends large volumes of data to the API. In our case, large consists of up to ~10MB per HTTP POST, but could be as small as a few KB. We'll be making many of these transactions, sending anywhere from a ~100MB to a 100GB during program execution.

The problem that we've encountered, is that our total bandwidth (total amount of data sent / (amount of time it takes to execute all upload transactions - server side processing time)) is quite bad. If we take the raw data and FTP it to the same webserver which hosts the Apache instance, we get ~5x more bandwidth than the current setup. We understand that sending the data in chunks will eat into performance to some degree, but a 5x slowdown seems excessive (maybe it's not, that's why we're asking!)

We're looking for suggestions to improve performance, or an argument as to why it can't be improved under our constraints. We must continue to use HTTP POSTs to send the data one chunk at a time. We're not tied to libcurl, if there is a faster alternative for our situation we'd be happy to integrate it into our application. Ideally there'd be some way to configure libcurl to perform better with our non-standard load (we've read about TCP_CORK, but weren't able to find any documentation on how to use it in libcurl).

Roughly, our code currently looks like this (error checking removed for terseness)

```
CURL *cur = curl_easy_init()))
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Connection: Keep-Alive");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Keep-Alive: 60");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: text/xml");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, xff); // xff declared elsewhere

curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_PROXY, proxyurl); // proxyurl declared elsewhere
// proxyauth declared elsewhere
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, proxyauth);
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_URL, urlbuf); // urlbuf declared elsewhere
// user_agent declared elsewhere
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, user_agent);
// callback makes a copy of a tiny (<100 byte) response which is processes later.
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, ptr); // ptr declared elsewhere
// postBody is the up to ~10MB data buffer being sent
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postBody);
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, postBodySize); // postBody size
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE);
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
// connectTimeout declared elsewhere
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, connectTimeout);
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout); // timeout declared elsewhere
/* Turn on http keep-alive packets */
curl_easy_setopt(cur, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1);

curl_easy_perform(cur)
```

Any and all thoughts/suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: "5x slowdown" - with large POSTs?

Comment: This may be relevant: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=925760 . Search the page for "UPDATE RESOLUTION".

Comment: @karoly-horvath more precisely, we are getting 1/5 the bandwidth of a generic FTP application sending all the data in one shot. If we take the data being sent as a single text file, compress it using deflate and FTP the resulting 125MB file with FileZilla, it takes about 2 minutes (8Mb/s). Our applications POSTs the data one chunk at a time, each individually compressed, so it's sending 175MB of data, but takes 14.5 minutes.

Comment: @pieman72 In the link you provide the poster is sending "very small" posts, and is trying to avoid nagling. We're sending large posts that will likely be broken up into multiple TCP packets anyway. Moreover, we're already using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. Are we missing something?

Comment: It will be less of an issue with larger files, but if your chunk size it small, it may still be a factor. I agree it's probably not a complete solution, sorry.

Comment: @pieman72 Less than 10% of our POSTs are smaller than 1500 bytes (standard MTU), most are going to need to be sent as multiple TCP/IP packets. The median postBodySize is 55KB with an average size of 1.6MB.